# Execution order inside a warp for divergent cases in CUDA

Tags: cuda

Trying to understand execution order within a warp. In the following diverging code what will be the execution order: 0,1,2----31 or 31,29,....0?

**A**

```
if (tid == 0)      { . . . }
else if (tid == 1) { . . . }
else if (tid == 2) { . . . }
. . .
else if (tid == 31){ . . . }
```

What if the case is this:

```
if(tid == 0) { . . . }
else 
{ . . . }
```

Comment: This is completely undefined, and if you need to know this or intend trying to relying on an order in your code, you are doing something wrong.

Comment: Why is this important to you? What are you trying to do? Perhaps restructuring your computation is a far better idea than trying to manage divergence at this level.